# Using sessions with cookies disabled?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I was wondering if there was a way to create a session even with cookies disabled on the browser? I have already tried the following:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = session_id(); 

session_id($_SESSION['id']);
```

didn't seem to work, I just wanted to know if this was even possible with cookies disabled?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible that I know of, not with normal sessions in PHP. You could maybe build something yourself that keeps track of the users IP + UserAgent or something, but I would not trust it.

Your best bet is to use HTML Session Storage. Here is a guide: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

The main problem with HTML storage (any kind) if that JavaScript reads it easely, but to get the info to the server you would need to add it to a hidden field and post it, or set it in all URLs.